# I update an array (key,value) object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I update an array (key,value) object?

```
arrTotals[
{DistroTotal: "0.00"},
{coupons: 12},
{invoiceAmount: "14.96"}
]
```

I want to update the 'DistroTotal' to a value.

I have tried

```
    for (var key in arrTotals) {
        if (arrTotals[key] == 'DistroTotal') {
            arrTotals.splice(key, 2.00);
        }
    }
```

Thanks ..

Comment: Array of js objects...

Comment: Arrays in JavaScript have numerical indexes (keys). As soon as you shove a non-numerical "index" into it, it's no longer an array.

Comment: @NullUserException my mistake, I thought it was saying `var arrTotals = [
{DistroTotal: "0.00"},
{coupons: 12},
{invoiceAmount: "14.96"}
]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing a level of nesting:

```
for (var key in arrTotals[0]) {
```

If you only need to work with that specific one, then just do:

```
arrTotals[0].DistroTotal = '2.00';
```

If you don't know where the object with the `DistroTotal` key is, or there are many of them, your loop is a bit different:

```
for (var x = 0; x < arrTotals.length; x++) {
    if (arrTotals[x].hasOwnProperty('DistroTotal') {
        arrTotals[x].DistroTotal = '2.00';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Since it sounds like you are trying to use a key/value dictionary. Consider switching to using an object instead of an array here.

```
arrTotals = { 
    DistroTotal: 0.00,
    coupons: 12,
    invoiceAmount: "14.96"
};

arrTotals["DistroTotal"] = 2.00;
```